# Correct nginx configuration to prevent indexing of some folders

Tags: nginx, googlebot

I'm using the following `Nginx` configuration to prevent the indexing of content in some of my folders when I use the `x-robots tag`

```
location ~ .*/(?:archive|filter|topic)/.* {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow";      
}
```

The content remains indexed but I can't debug the `Nginx` configuration.

My questions: is the configuration I use correct and if I should wait till googlebot re-crawls content and de-indexes the content? Or is my configuration wrong?

Comment: Have you tried plain old `robots.txt`?

Comment: Anyway, I guess, you have some other rules in your config. I'm pretty sure this location is not used. Show full config

Comment: @AlexeyTen robots.txt doesn't prevent indexing. The question is only: is the syntax of configuration correct: yes/no?

Comment: `robots.txt` is **exactly** the tool to prevent indexing. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en _A robots.txt file is a file at the root of your site that indicates those parts of your site you don’t want accessed by search engine crawlers_

Comment: @AlexeyTen dude, if you don't know the difference between indexing and crawling, be quite, please, and rtfm.

Comment: **Syntax** of this snippet is correct, but it does not mean it works

Comment: So tell me difference…

Comment: wow, i'll archive this one - what a kind of funny things tell guys from yandex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The configuration you've written is correct. I'd give one caveat (assuming your config is otherwise standard):

It will only output the X-Robots-Tag when the result code is 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307 (e.g. content matches a disk file, a redirect is issued, etc.). So if you have an `/archive/index.html`, a hit to `http://yoursite.com/archive/` will give the header. If the `index.html` does not exist (404), you won't see the tag.

The `always` parameter will output the header for all response codes, assuming the location block is processed:

```
location ~ .*/(?:archive|filter|topic)/.* {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" always;      
}
```

Another option will guarantee the header is output on a URI match. This is useful for when there's a chance that a location block may not get processed (due to short-circuiting, like with [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) or a `last` on a rewrite etc):

```
http {
    ...
    map $request_uri $robot_header {
        default "";
        ~.*/(?:archive|filter|topic)/.* "noindex, follow";
    }

    server {
        ...
        add_header X-Robots-Tag $robot_header;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Interesting point with `index.html`. How should configuration look alike, if `http://yoursite.com/archive/` is a kind of symlink, or if this url is built by rewrite rule?